# delete_if/select Array of Objects by passing in hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have an array of objects (a) with fields :state and :country. I also have a hash with `h[:state] = "TN"` `h[:country] = "US"`. I know that I can use select/delete_if by explicitly stating the attributes like so:

```
a.select{ |l| l.state == h[:state] && l.country == h[:country] }
```

My question is, is there a way to just pass in the hash like you can do with something like an activeRecord query? I tried `a.select(h)` but that just gives me a an array of empty hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each element of your `a` is a `Struct`, you can do it like this:

```
a.select{|l| l.to_h == h}
```